# Locating my backup files

Tags: networking

I have just installed ubuntu. I used to run XP and have backed up all my files to a WD backup drive which is connected to my wireless router. Trouble is, I do not know how to access this drive. My Android phone sees them but I do not know how to this with Ubuntu applications. Any suggestions/guidance will be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Show us what your phone is "seeing". Also the Sharing page of the router would be helpfull.

Comment: How did you access them from windows?

Answer (score -1):

Use your file manager (nautilus, pcmanfm ..) And search for the word network, or put  `smb://`  in the address bar.

If the address bar is locked use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to unlock it

By default the samba client is already installed on Ubuntu, but if it is not, just install it; in terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```